# Declaring multiples in the gemfile (Same feature, different gem). Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec, cucumber, haml

I've come across a few tutorials where the author declares two versions of the same gem in the gemfile, even in the same group.

```
"haml" and "haml-rails"
"rspec" and "rspec-rails"
"cucumber" and "cucumber-rails"
```

and there are more examples of this....

Why is this done? Is this a better way to work with these gems rather than declaring a single gem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, these are not the same gems. Rails versions usually extend the standard libraries.

But because `foo-rails` has `foo` in its dependencies ([see example here](https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber-rails)), you just need `foo-rails` in your Gemfile (Bundler is just great).

Comment: Does this mean those who are declaring both gems "cucumber" and "cucumber-rails" are doing it wrong by being redundant?

Comment: It is wrong, because it's not harmless. You could wind up with different versions of the gem.

Comment: Bundler handles this for you and shout when incompatibilities are found

Comment: Right. And if you declare both gems explicitly, you make it harder for Bundler to resolve the dependencies, and introduce more opportunity for error.

Answer (score 0):

cucumber-rails is not the same gem as Cucumber. It's got Cucumber as a dependency, as well as some Rails-specific stuff. So as apneadiving said, if you include cucumber-rails in your Gemfile, it should load Cucumber too.

Comment: Does this mean those who are declaring both gems "cucumber" and "cucumber-rails" are doing it wrong by being redundant?

Comment: Yes. Or there may be an old version of cucumber-rails that didn't have that dependency.